# Copy the previous input content with a button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some html and jQuery as follows:

```js
$(".btn-copy").click(function() {
  var previousContent = $(this).prev()[0];
  previousContent.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-fiche item-hidden">
  <label>
        Identifier
        <input type="text" name="login-1" placeholder="Write you login" value="My login">
        <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
    </label>
  <label>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password-1" placeholder="Write your password" value="My password">
        <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
        <button class="btn-save">Save</button>
    </label>
</div>
```

When I click the first copy button, then, "My login" is copied properly.
But when I click the second copy button, the copy isn't updated, like if no element were found although I can see the password being selected when I click the button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input field with type `password` doesn't support copying of its content for security purposes. If you want to copy, you must change field type to `text`, copy text and then change back to `password`.

```js
$(".btn-copy").click(function() {
  var previousContent = $(this).prev()[0];
  var fieldType = previousContent.type; // Saving orig field type

  // Set current type to 'text'
  previousContent.type = 'text';
  previousContent.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');

  // Return back orig type for field
  previousContent.type = fieldType;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-fiche item-hidden">
  <label>
        Identifier
        <input type="text" name="login-1" placeholder="Write you login" value="My login">
        <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
    </label>
  <label>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password-1" placeholder="Write your password" value="My password">
        <button class="btn-copy">Copy</button>
        <button class="btn-save">Save</button>
    </label>
</div>
```